# How to fix 'response.json is not a function' in async/await function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to turn my response into json. I'm not quite sure I'm getting `TypeError: response.json is not a function` error. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

```
    componentDidMount(){
        this.timingFunction = setInterval(() => this.getAllStations(), 1000);
    }


    async getAllStations(){
        try{
            const response = await(`http:api.bart.gov/api/etd.aspx?cmd=etd&orig=${this.state.selectedStation}&key=${bartKey}&json=y`);
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log(`Here: ${data}`)


        }catch(e){
            console.log(`Error: ${e}`)
        }

    }
```

I expected to see the json response but got the error message.
edit: Added await in front of response.json(); and got no where.

Comment: why using async.. can be done using promises..

Comment: @user7417866 That's true. However, this should work with async as well.

Comment: async and await is for promises not for fetching data from server / url, best way to use is ajax for server fetch code.

Comment: more specifically, await causes async function to pause till Promise is fulfilled, but in your case its fetching response from URL and not promises

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're missing the call to fetch (or whatever else you use to get data from the api). Right now it looks like you've mistaken `await` for a function.

`` const response = await(`http:api.bart.gov... ``

(You're also missing the two slashes after the `http` but that's not a problem yet.)

Try this:

`` const response = await fetch(`http://api.bart.gov... ``

Comment: Man thank you so much.  I can't believe I missed that

Answer (score 7):

You are using await as a function

`await` is a system to wait for a promise only, instead of doing

> const response = await('http:...');

You should do

```
const response = await fetch('http:...');
```

Comment: `You are using await as a function`. No this it is `await expression` and `expression` here is `('http:...')`, and as the braces here are not relevant is equal to `await 'http:...'` (Like `const foo = ('bar')` is equivalent to `const foo = 'bar'`). The right-hand side of an `await` expression can be any type of value, if it is not a Promise, then it will be converted to a resolved Promise. So it is essentially equivalent to `const response = await Promise.resolve('http:...');`