# Uncaught TypeError: response.json is not a function at HTMLButtonElement

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, async-await, fetch

I am stuck with this I am new to web development, any help would be highly appreciated. Can't figure out what's wrong in my code, I get an error Uncaught TypeError: response.json is not a function

```js
const getButton = document.querySelector('.get')
function getData(){
  const response = fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users");
  const data = response.json();
  console.log(data)
}
 getButton.addEventListener('click',getData)
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button class="get">GET</button>
    </div>
    <script src="sandbox.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `fetch` is asynchronous function. I'd suggest starting with studying its documentation [at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix 'response.json is not a function' in async/await function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454932/how-to-fix-response-json-is-not-a-function-in-async-await-function)

Comment: `response` is a `Promise`. You have to wait for it to fulfill either with `await` (only works in an `async` function) or with `.then()`

Answer (score 1):

Using [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
const getButton = document.querySelector('.get')

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users");
  const data = await response.json();
  console.log(data)
}

getButton.addEventListener('click', getData)
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <button class="get">GET</button>
  </div>
  <script src="sandbox.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: As OP is a beginner... Please add an explanation why OPs script doesn't work, why `await` helps and why OP also needs `async`. So OP understands the underlying problem and to make this answer more valuable for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, fetch() is asynchronous. Try this:

```
const getButton = document.querySelector('.get')
function getData(){
    const response = fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users")
        .then(function(data) {
            // This will run on on response from the server
            // AAA
            console.log(data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            // Deal with errors here
        });
    // BBB
}
getButton.addEventListener('click',getData);
```

so code at BBB will probably run before the code at AAA